# No Power Going to my new GFCI

Tags: electrical

I have installed a Leviton 15amp GFCI.  The one I replaced said 15Amps on it's metal tab but it also said 20A on the body.  The breaker that feeds this outlet is 15Amp.  After I replaced it, I was not getting any power to the unit other than a small green light at the bottom corner of the new GFCI.  I used a pen-tester and it showed power going to one of the black wires that connect to the lower side of the GFCI, but the other wires (white & black) had no power.

Any ideas out there as to what I am doing wrong?  Thanks.

Comment: Read the instructions carefully.  Make sure you are following the instructions to push the buttons as required to set the device, different receptacles will have different instructions.  Make sure the fed from the panel is on the LINE terminals and the feed to downstream receptacles is on the LOAD terminals.

Comment: There is a "LOAD" side and "LINE" side on the GFCI outlet, and they must be wired correctly.  "LINE" will be supply voltage coming from the breaker box, and "LOAD" is a pair that continues on to another, protected outlet.

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out.

Th new GFCI reversed the line and load terminals from what the old GFCI had.  All I did was to reverse the white and black (hot) wires and everything works fine.

I hope this will help others out in the future.

Matt

Comment: Fortunately, most (all?) GFCI's are designed to not power on when the line is connected to the load side. This used to not be the case, and it was possible to install the GFCI backwards and have no protection on the circuit at all.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem and finally solved it. I bought a Leviton GFCI receptacle and installed it according to the instruction.But after I turned on power,the device could not be reset and no power came out.

Solution: Switch line ween connections between top and bottom terminals.
Leviton should be shamed of itself.

Comment: No, this isn't Leviton's fault (unless they put the sticker on the wrong set of terminals somehow) -- it sounds like you mixed up the LINE and LOAD ends of the GFCI, and the GFCI was doing the right thing by protecting you from that rather bad miswiring.